# jquery validation condition prevent submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

how to create jquery for prevent form submit if status=1(from database)
 can't submit else can submit,where status i get from database.i'm so confused?

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="myAnchor" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>actrecord/add/<?php echo $data[0]->activity_id;?>">
```

```html
<th><button onclick="warning()" type="submit" class="btn blue">new activity</button></th>
```

```html
<script>
document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
</script>

<script>function warning(){ alert("selesaikan dulu aktiiftas sebelumnya");} </script>
```

Comment: What status are you referring to and what are you trying to accomplish? What type of input is in your form?

Comment: status not type input but status is name column in database.where i can see status from database.so if i see status=1 in database form can't input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onsubmit trigger in your form:

```
<form method='POST' action='blah' onsubmit='return check()'>
```

Then, in javascript with jquery:

```
<script>
function check()
{
   $.ajax({
      url:checkStatus.php,
      success:function(data){
           return (data==1)? false : true;
      }
   });
}
</script>
```

Just make sure checkStatus.php will echo the status from the db.